# How to compress all subfolders to separate files in bash?

Tags: bash, compression

How can I compress all the subfolders? For example:

```
backup
└─weekly
  ├─username1
  ├─username2
  ├─username3
  └─…more
```

So how can I compress all those subfolders into individual files? For example `username1.tar.gz`, `username2.tar.gz` and it will send to specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
for dir in *; do tar czvf "$dir".tar.gz "$dir";done
```